# Can't receive external email in virtualmin

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot, webmin, virtualmin

I have installed postfix and dovecot and webmin + virtualmin on my ubuntu server 
to run a mail server I followed virtualmin tutorial how to set it up.

but now I can send outgoing mails but I can't receive out coming emails ! I just can receive mail from local users.

any idea how to fix it ?

this is postconf -n output :

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
import_environment = MAIL_CONFIG MAIL_DEBUG MAIL_LOGTAG TZ XAUTHORITY DISPLAY LANG=C RESOLV_MULTI=on
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = mail.karshenasan-nezam.com, karshenasan-nezam.com, localhost.com, , localhost
myhostname = karshenasan-nezam.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = mail.karshenasan-nezam.com
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/dependent
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Comment: You might want to check the postfix logs, and if necessary bump up the log level.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks for reply, I've been checking mail log and i couldn't find any log or error about receiving outcoming emails. is postfix log separate from mail log in webmin ? if so how can i check postfix log ?

Comment: Well,iirc postfix logs to syslog. Check there.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I've check syslog but there weren't any activity for receiving email! while i have sent a mail from another server to this mail account but there was no activity on this server and no receiving mail!

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I just get this error after about 1 hour of sending mail to webmin mail server : `This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
A message that you sent has not yet been delivered to one or more of its
recipients after more than 24 hours on the queue on marya.firsthost.com.

The message identifier is:     1ZkHtA-0007z9-3C
The date of the message is:    Fri, 09 Oct 2015 00:04:08 +0330
The subject of the message is: 122222

Comment: @JourneymanGeek and : 
`The address to which the message has not yet been delivered is:

  info@myserver.com

No action is required on your part. Delivery attempts will continue for
some time, and this warning may be repeated at intervals if the message
remains undelivered. Eventually the mail delivery software will give up,
and when that happens, the message will be returned to you.`